# How to start making a website that gets photos from flickr using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, flickr

I'm pretty new to rails so where can I get resources to help me get this done? What gems do I need? How do I use flickr api inside of the website using rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'flickr_fu' gem its very simple to use https://github.com/commonthread/flickr_fu.
Please Visit http://www.pixellatedvisions.com/2009/04/06/integrating-flickr-into-your-rails-website

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nice gem named `flickraw` to do that. 
Please checkout the following links:

[Flickraw RDoc](http://hanklords.github.com/flickraw)

[Integrating Flickr into your Rails website](http://code.flickr.net/2009/04/09/integrating-flickr-into-your-rails-website/)